# Can't cast database type tsvector to String

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm just getting started with PostgreSQL and am trying to perform a full text search. I've got some records in the table, with a column `search` of type `tsvector`. That all works great. However, using Npgsql, I'm trying to execute:

```
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT search FROM data";
    cmd.Prepare();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

But I keep getting an `InvalidCastException` saying

> Can't cast database type tsvector to String

I assume there's something more I need to add for it to correctly convert the types, but documentation for NpgSql seems to be virtually non-existent. Is this just not something that can be done, or should I be doing it differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any knowledge of NpgsqlCommand, but have you tried something like this:

```
var stringResponse= cmd.ExecuteReader().GetString(0);
```

Comment: Not quite exactly that syntax, but you got me thinking on the right track, so I'll mark this as accepted. For some reason my debugger was breaking on my `ExecuteReader()`, but the problem was actually with `GetString(0)`, which I was doing a little farther down. I assumed that simply got a string representation of whatever was in that field (similar to C# `.ToString()`). But apparently not. `GetValue(0)` is what worked for me.